# How do I solve my issue with the forEach loop not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

I keep getting an error saying .forEach is not a function I have a very similar function that runs just fine but I can't figure out how to fix this forEach issue

```
function populateRepsDiv(repsArray) {
  removeChildren(senatorDiv)
  repsArray.forEach(representative => {
    const repFigure = document.createElement('figure')
    const repImg = document.createElement('img')
    const repCaption = document.createElement('figcaption')

    repImg.src = representative.imgURL
    repCaption.textContent = representative.name

    repFigure.appendChild(repImg)
    repFigure.appendChild(figCaption)
    senatorDiv.appendChild(repFigure)

    console.log(representative.name)
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are calling this function?

Comment: Are you sure repsArray is actually an array? If you console.log(repsArray) right before the repsArray.forEach(representative => { does it display as an array?

Comment: I added the console.log before repsArray and it is displaying as a function I think do I have syntax error?

Comment: this is what the console log displayed       `ƒ simplifiedReps() {
      return representatives.map(representative => {
        const middleName = representative.middle_name ? ` ${representative.middle_name} ` : ``
        return {

Comment: I figured out I had snytax error with the simpleReps array and that cause it not be be a array.